# python: combine 2 ordered lists into list of tuples

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have 2 lists that I want to combine into a single list of tuples, so that order is maintained and the `result[i]` is `(first[i], second[i])`.  Assume that the two lists will always be of the same size.  Is there a way to do this using list comprehension?  So for example:

```
>>> first = [1,2,3]
>>> second = [4,5,6]
>>> combine(first, second)
[(1,4), (2,5), (3,6)]
```

I've tried a few things

```
[(i,j) for i in first, j in second]
[(i for i in first, j for j in second)]
[(i,j) for i,j in first, second]
```

None of these work.  I'm just wondering if this is possible or if I have to do it using a loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use zip:

```
list(zip(first, second))
Out[384]: [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Comment: Why wrap it in `list`? Am I missing some edge case in my plain use of `zip`?

Comment: @Spacedman In Python 3, zip() returns an iterator instead of a list. I added that so it works for both versions.

Comment: `zip` certainly serves the purpose, but just for the sake of the question, is it possible with list comprehension or not?

Comment: The kind of comprehension you look for (iterating over multple lists) is generally done with zip (`[(i, j) for (i, j) in zip(first, second)]`) (of course it is unnecessary here but you get the idea) But you can also do something like this `[(first[i], second[i]) for i in range(len(first))]`

Answer (score 6):

Python has a function for that:

```
>>> zip(first, second)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

zippedy-doo-dah

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
>>> first = [1,2,3]
>>> second = [4,5,6]
>>> list(zip(first, second))
[(1,4), (2,5), (3,6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> first = [1,2,3]
>>> second = [4,5,6]
>>> list =zip(first,second)
>>> list
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

or also for lists instead of tuple, using numpy

```
>>> lista = [first,second]
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(lista)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> np.array(lista)[:,0]
array([1, 4])
>>> np.array(lista)[:,1]
array([2, 5])
>>> np.array(lista)[:,2]
array([3, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use izip:

```
>>> first = [1,2,3]
>>> second = [4,5,6]

>>> from itertools import izip
>>> gen = izip(first, second)
>>> [(i, j) for i, j in gen]
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```